# AngularJS ng-show not working with $timeout?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, timeout, angularjs-ng-show

I want to selected tab and showing 2 buttons.

so this is my aspx code :

```
 <button id="UxMoveAllRight" style="width: 40px; height: 25px; margin-top: 20px;" ng-show="showMoveallButtons()">
                                <i class="pi-icon pi-icon-angle-double-right"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button id="UxMoveAllLeft" style="width: 40px; height: 25px; margin-bottom: 20px;" ng-show="showMoveallButtons()">
                                <i class="pi-icon pi-icon-angle-double-left"></i>
                            </button>
```

and this is my ng-show function code (in controller.js):

```
$scope.showMoveallButtons = function () {
                    var show = false;
                    $timeout(function () {
                        var activetab = $find("Add").get_selectedTab().get_name();
                        if (activetab == "AddBulk") { show = true }
                        else { show = false };
                    });
                    return show;
                };
```

but always return false.
I want to, if selected tab equals AddBulk , showing 2 button else not showing.

I guess, always return false reason : timeout ?

Do you any idea about how can I fix ?

Comment: In your code `return show;` is like `return false;` **always**

Comment: What do you mean ? Where am I doing wrong @Tushar

Comment: Point the `ng-show` to a scope property and change it inside timeout.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> $timeout(function () {
>                           var activetab = $find("Add").get_selectedTab().get_name();
>                           if (activetab == "AddBulk") { show = true }
>                           else { show = false };
>                           return show;
>                       });

Comment: This is not the best way since $timeout() is a async function, the code after $timeout will alway run before it.

Answer (score 0):

**Just put in controller($timeout)**

'use strict';

```
app.controller('ctrlname', ['$scope','$http','$timeout', function($scope,$http,$timeout){

        ......
        ......
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope.show` in your `timeOut()` and affect her in your directive `ng-show.`

**JS**

```
$scope.showMoveallButtons = function () {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        var activetab = $find("Add").get_selectedTab().get_name();
                        if (activetab == "AddBulk") { $scope.show= true }
                        else { $scope.show= false };
                    },/*Your delay here*/);
                };
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="UxMoveAllRight" style="width: 40px; height: 25px; margin-top: 20px;" ng-show="show">
```